# How do i delete a file in the xxxx.app directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I have the following code:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"txt"];

if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path1]) {
    NSLog(@"-- sample file found --");


    AccessQuestionsDB *accessQuestionDataFunction = [AccessQuestionsDB new];
    idCounter = [accessQuestionDataFunction populateTheDatabase: path1 theID:0 firstTime: YES];

    [accessQuestionDataFunction release];

    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:path1 error:NULL];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path1]) {
        NSLog (@"Remove %@ successful", path1);
    } else {
        NSLog (@"Remove %@ failed", path1);
    }

}
else {
    NSLog(@"-- NO SAMPLE FILE! --");
}
```

Output:

```
2011-06-13 21:41:04.471 xxxx[1726:707] Remove /var/mobile/Applications/B1CC3E09-2A1D-4CD7-976D-E190A238EC79/xxxx.app/myFile.txt successful
```

When i run the program it indicate that the file is deleted, see above, but it is not. When i check, using "iPhone Explorer" the files still resides in the "xxxx.app" directory, which i guess is the root directory for the application.

I would really appreciate if someone nice could show me how to really delete this file as i need it removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add or remove files from the .app bundle once it has been signed and placed on the device.

Comment: can you please recommend how i should do this so i get rid of these files?

Comment: Why are you trying to get rid of files?

Comment: i thought it was a good idea, just changed that strategy so thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can't delete files in the app bundle.
Also,

```
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path1]) {
    NSLog (@"Remove %@ successful", path1);
} else {
    NSLog (@"Remove %@ failed", path1);
}
```

outputs "Remove successful" because you output that when `fileExistsAtPath`, i.e. when it was not deleted.

Comment: uhhhhhh i am really stupid, i have been looking at this for so long time now :-(